# User logins over past month

Tags: user-account, logs

OK I'm sure this is really easy but I cant find out how to do it.

I simply want to know how many users have logged in each month so that I can track activity.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Can you add what CMS you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User authentication and management when using CiviCRM are handled by your CMS of choice (CiviCRM standalone aside).

For Wordpress, I've had good success with [User Login History](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-login-history/) to generate data to report on Monthly Active Users (MAU) to see how much usage the CRM is getting. You'll need to export the CSV, trim it to get only the successful logins and group by User ID, etc to get that figure.

Comment: For Drupal a suitable module would be "Login History": https://www.drupal.org/project/login_history

Comment: ah ok i see. Many thanks.